# Delphi DBText displays #### instead of number

Tags: oracle, delphi

I am using 3 TDBText components on my form and using the following SQL to populate them:

```
TO_CHAR(myField, '0000.00') "AMOUNT"
```

where myField are 3 different numeric fields.

One of them is displaying correctly (eg '9983.66'), but the other 2 are displaying as '#######'.  I've checked the properties for each DBText and they are identical (apart from the field).

Comment: I don't know Delphi, but - such an output is *usually* result of wrongly set format mask. Looks like those other 2 numbers are *larger* than 9999. Are they?

Comment: @Littlefoot, yes they were

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just figured it out.  There weren't enough zeros in the mask to accomadate the number.  I've changed the format to '000000.00' and it's working fine

Comment: That's the whole idea of displaying `###`: to indicate something's wrong (most commonly: not enough space or wrong format). It would be far more riskful to just display a portion of digits (as per space or format).